# Wicket setting window close callback not possible everywhere?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a modal window with form inside it. There are two way user can close the window: either by filling up correctly form and submit change, or clicking an "x" in top right corner.

Now I'm trying to do following thing:

When user sucesfully fills up the form and submit change, on parent page I'm trying to display (with jQuery) some information about success.

When user clicks an "x" I want the modal window to be closed without any additional info. However **setWindowClosedCallback** is not working as I expected. Take a look at my code, first I'm getting reference to modalWindow (I omitted some not interesting parts of the code like adding form inputs etc.):

```
public EditEmailForm( String id, final ModalWindow modalWindow,final User u )
{
    super( id );
    modalWindow.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback() 
    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) 
    {
            //here some code doing jQuery magic for parent page
    }
});
    AjaxSubmitLink closeBtn = new AjaxCloseCancelBtn( "close-x", this );

    add( new AjaxSubmitLink( "save", this )
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit( AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form )
        {
        //here's user info change
        }

        @Override
        protected void onError( AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form )
        {
            target.add( feedbackPanel );
        }
    } );
    add( closeBtn );
}


protected class AjaxCloseCancelBtn extends AjaxSubmitLink
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AjaxCloseCancelBtn( String id, Form<?> form )
    {
        super( id, form );
        setDefaultFormProcessing( false );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit( AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form )
    {
        modalWindow.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback() 
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClose( AjaxRequestTarget arg0 )
            {               
            }

        });
        // revert fields values
        form.clearInput();
        // close popup
        modalWindow.close( target );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError( AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form )
    {
    }

}
```

This code works 50% good, as it displays what I want on parent page, but it also does it when I hit an "x" even tho I'm trying to set new window close callback which is empty. Any solution how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.modal.ModalWindow.close(AjaxRequestTarget)